# How to prove $ \mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\text{Im}f(x')}{x'-x} = \mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x'\text{Im}f(x')}{x'^2-x^2} $

Tags: complex-analysis

How to prove

$$ \mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\text{Im}f(x')}{x'-x} dx' = \mathcal{P}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{x'\text{Im}f(x')}{x'^2-x^2} dx' $$

if $\text{Im}f(x)$ is odd, and $\mathcal{P}$ is Cauch principal value

Comment: Is $\mathcal{P}$ principal value? Are you integrating with respect to $x'$?

Comment: Yes, my bad (I corrected the data)